# Is it possible to use generic parameter value in conditional type result field in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

Well, I want to write a bit tricky generic function type for transforming data.
For single object it's easy:

```
export type SingleObjFunction<InputDataType, OutputDataType> =
  (object: InputDataType) => OutputDataType;
```

However, for array of objects I want the function which return either an object with `field: OutputDataType[]` property inside, or plain array;
Is it possible to get this key of property from another generic parameter, like this:

```
export type MultipleObjFunction<
  InputDataType, 
  OutputDataType, 
  InnerField extends (string | undefined), 
  FunctionResult = InnerField extends string
    ? { [Key: valueof InnerField]: OutputDataType[] }
    : OutputDataType[]
> = (objs: InputDataType[]) => FunctionResult
```

I know there is no such thing as `valueof`, but may be there is another way to do so?

Comment: Do you mean like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5PBVw)? If so, I can write up an answer including an explanation. If not, can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, thanks! I totally forgot about Record type, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [default type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints) and [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to build the type parameter `FunctionResult` before using it as the return type of your function.

The compiler will use the resolved type of the `InnerField` type parameter (which is set to `undefined` by default if no type argument is provided when invoking the function) to make a determination: if that resolved type is assignable to a `string`, then the return type will be an object type `Record<InnerField, OutputDataType[]>`, else it will be an array type `OutputDataType[]`.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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)

```ts
type MultipleObjFunction<
  InputDataType, 
  OutputDataType, 
  InnerField extends (string | undefined) = undefined,
  FunctionResult = InnerField extends string
    ? Record<InnerField, OutputDataType[]>
    : OutputDataType[]
> = (objs: InputDataType[]) => FunctionResult;

type In = {
  str: string;
  num: number;
};

type Out = { result: string };

declare const arg: In;

declare const f1: MultipleObjFunction<In, Out>;
const r1 = f1([arg]);
    //^? const r1: Out[]

declare const f2: MultipleObjFunction<In, Out, 'myPropertyName'>;
const r2 = f2([arg]);
    //^? const r2: Record<"myPropertyName", Out[]>
type R2Key = keyof typeof r2;
   //^? type R2Key = "myPropertyName"
r2.myPropertyName
 //^? (property) myPropertyName: Out[]
```